# Using amp-selector inside amp-carousel

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to render multiple images using amp-selector inside amp-carousel but the images are not loading. If I try to have amp-carousel inside the amp-selector tag then the images are rendering but that is not my use case.

Can someone explain the issue and suggest another way?

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html amp4email data-css-strict>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
    <style amp-custom>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <amp-carousel id="carousel-1" height="60" controls>
        <amp-selector layout="container" name="x1">
            <amp-img
                     alt="0" src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/fr/view-image.php?image=151128&picture=aurora-borealis-earth-magic"
                     width="52"
                     height="52"
                     option="0"
                     ></amp-img>
            <amp-img
                     alt="0" src="https://www.istockphoto.com/fr/photos/inde"
                     width="52"
                     height="52"
                     option="0"
                     ></amp-img>
            <amp-img
                     alt="2" src="https://pixabay.com/fr/images/search/nature/"
                     width="52"
                     height="52"
                     option="2"
                     ></amp-img>
        </amp-selector>
        <amp-selector layout="container" name="x1">
            <amp-img
                     alt="0" src="https://www.istockphoto.com/fr/photos/paris"
                     width="52"
                     height="52"
                     option="0"
                     ></amp-img>
            <amp-img
                     alt="0" src="https://www.istockphoto.com/fr/photos/inde"
                     width="52"
                     height="52"
                     option="0"
                     ></amp-img>
            <amp-img
                     alt="2" src="https://pixabay.com/fr/images/search/nature/"
                     width="52"
                     height="52"
                     option="2"
                     ></amp-img>
        </amp-selector>
      </amp-carousel>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of things done wrong. `SRC` attribute in `AMP-IMG` linked to the page, but not to the image, `SRC` attribute has to end with `.jpg`, `.png`, `.svg` etc... Second thing is that image width and height has to be same as image dimensions. Here is working example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/egor_nmore/pen/NWYRrwM).

Comment: I have given dummy values for <img> tag. My question is different.

Comment: @Dennon Then it's difference in image dimensions and width/height attributes. Did you checked my codepen?